# Get the body of an incoming email in an Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I want to process incoming mails coming from an exchange server and save it in my mail box. As of now I can get an alert for every incoming mail.

How can I get the body of the email to process it?

```
   public partial class ThisAddIn
   {
            private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Application.NewMail += new ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(AlertWhenNewMail);
            }
            void AlertWhenNewMail()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("New Email Recieved");
            }

            private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
            }
            #region VSTO generated code
            private void InternalStartup()
            {
               this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
               this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
            }
            #endregion
    }
```

Also, how to save the email and then just store it in the inbox folder?

Comment: What version of Outlook are we talking here?

Comment: it is for outlook 2007..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get to the actual mailItem, use the entryID passed in the newMailEx event. Your response to other posts suggests this doesn't work for you somehow, but I'll assume we'll get that sorted out and provide you some example code:

```
void MyApplication_NewMailEx(string anEntryID)
{
  Outlook.NameSpace namespace = this.GetNamespace("MAPI");  
  Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = this.Session.GetDefaultFolder( Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox );
  Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem) outlookNS.GetItemFromID( anEntryID, folder.StoreID );

  // ... process the mail item
}
```

To answer the second part of your question, once you get hold of the mail item through this event it has *already been saved into your inbox*, so no need to do anything there. You'd save it to disk using [MailItem.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175283%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Where can I get some documentation/tutorial to write Outlook Add Ins?No resource seems to be present regarding this on the Internet, apart from a couple of articles on MSDN.

Comment: Paul-jan, i only get email sender address,subject but not body,

Comment: Did you try both *MailItem.Body* and *Mailitem.HTMLBody*? Might be worth starting a separate question on the topic.

Comment: Hi Above code is not working. It gives exception in Last line of Code in Visual studio 2012 and Outlook 2010

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Application.NewMail` event, try [`Application.NewMailEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147646%28office.12%29.aspx) with gives you a parameter `EntryIDCollection` (A string representing an Entry ID of an item received in the Inbox) with which you should be able to retrieve the new email. MSDN page has a simple example.

Comment: i tried it like this     OutLookApp.NewMailEx += new ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(OutLookApp_NewMailEx); [outlookapp_newmailex does not exist in the current context]

Comment: You are aware you are using the Outlook 2003(!) object model?

Comment: Which should still contain that event, by the way.

Comment: your event consumer, OutLookApp_NewMailEx(), needs a parameter for the incoming email id like this OutLookApp_NewMailEx(string id)

Answer (score 2):

Here you have the answer for Outlook 2010. One line of code in your NewMailEx event:

```
    void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
    {    
        Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem) Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

        // do whatever you want with the new email...
    }
```

Comment: @Shyamsundarshah this code only works in Outlook 2010, do not try any other version.